# Auto discover and interact over AllJoyn

Tags: java, service-discovery, alljoyn

I am fairly new to AllJoyn and have been trying to use Java APIs to develop an AllJoyn compatible app. I went through all the sample Java and Android App and I can run them without any problem. But in all the samples, I observed that they follow a client/service model. At compile time, the client has to know about the interface that service implements. Following are few snapshots from demo code.

```
// From ObserverSample for Android
ProxyBusObject obj = (ProxyBusObject) msg.obj;
Door door = obj.getInterface(Door.class);

// From JavaSDKDocAboutClient
mProxyObj = mBus.getProxyBusObject (busName, "/example/path". sessionId.value, new Class<?>[] { SampleInterface.class});
```

I am trying to develop a service that has certain Properties, BusMethods, and BusSignals. I want this service to be discoverable and controllable from a third party AllJoyn application (AllJoyn dashboard app as an example) without the application knowing about my client interface to begin with.

I am not able to find out how to achieve this, as wherever I look, it appears that the interface I will use for my service, the client must know about it already to support my service. How is this possible from scaling point of view? There may be numerous services present now or may comeup in future, it will not be feasible to already know about their interfaces.

It will be helpful if someone can please point me to resources where I can find more information on developing such a service.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your client Java application doesn't have information about the service interface then you need to create a native C++ library that communicates with your java part and leverage the alljoyn introspection.
Using C++, you can programmatically call methods or get properties without having that information hardcoded like you have Java.

For more info, take a look at the eventaction sample in /alljoyn_core/samples
https://git.allseenalliance.org/cgit/core/alljoyn.git/snapshot/alljoyn-16.04.zip

Comment: Thank you Lino for pointing in the right direction. I was able to develop a discoverable application in C++ and controlpanel sample app was very helpful resource.